# How to disable empty space around the center circumference of the 3D function(using Maple13 and plot3d())?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, math-software, maple

When I try to plot 3D functions like the equation of a sphere with Maple13 on Linux(OS) using plot3d() I see empty space around the center circumference of the graph.

I understand it might be useful for others(for example to inspect the inner part of the graphed object) but I want to see the full drawn graph as it is.

How can I remove this gap? Is there any option in plot3d() that remove this gap?

For example, if I execute:

```
with(plots);

plot3d({-(5^2-(x-1)^2-(y-2)^2)^(1/2)+2, (5^2-(x-1)^2-(y-2)^2)^(1/2)+2}, x = -10 .. 10, y = -10 .. 10, scaling = constrained);
```

I see empty space around the center rim of the sphere along with the drawn graph?

Is it possible to kindly tell me how to disable it so that I can see the full drawn graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a slightly different approach, for example,

```
plots:-implicitplot3d( 5^2-(x-1)^2-(y-2)^2-(z-2)^2,
                       x = -10..10, y = -10..10, z=-10..10,
                       grid=[20,20,20], axes=box);

plots:-display(plottools:-sphere([1,2,2],5), axes=box,
               view=[-4..6,-3..7,-3..7]);
```

and you could adjust the various options for look & feel: view ranges, lighting, surface style, etc.

Comment: Thanks acer. That solves my problem.